# Combinatorial Proofs of Real Analysis Identity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, partial-fractions

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75681), a proof using real analysis is given of the following identity: $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n-1)!}{n \prod_{i=1}^{n} (a+i)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(a+k)^2}$$

Is there a combinatorial proof of this identity? Is so, does the proof require that $a$ be a natural number? Also is there an easy way to verify if combinatorial proofs exist of particular identities?

Comment: I can answer the final question: No.