# Compute: $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^4+1}{x^6+1}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to compute: $$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x^4+1}{x^6+1}\,dx.$$

I tried to change $x^{4}$ into $t^{2}$ or $t$, but it didn't work for me.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: $\mathrm{d}x$ went missing!

Comment: W.A. says that you should use partial fractions...

Comment: W.A. says it is $\pi/3$.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way for computing it easily without using W.A...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Edited** Here is a much simpler version of the previous answer.

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^4+1}{x^6+1}dx =\int_0^1 \frac{x^4-x^2+1}{x^6+1}dx+ \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{x^6+1}dx$$

After canceling the first fraction, and subbing $y=x^3$ in the second we get:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^4+1}{x^6+1}dx =\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2+1}dx+ \frac{1}{3}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{y^2+1}dy = \frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{12}=\frac{\pi}{3} \,.$$

**P.S.** Thanks to Zarrax for pointing the stupid mistakes I did...

Answer (score 9):

The denominator of the integrand $f(x):=\dfrac{x^{4}+1}{x^{6}+1}$ may be factored as
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^{6}+1 &=&\left( x^{2}+1\right) \left( x^{4}-x^{2}+1\right)  \
&=&\left( x^{2}+1\right) \left( x^{2}-\sqrt{3}x+1\right) \left( x^{2}+\sqrt{3
}x+1\right) 
\end{eqnarray*}

If you expand $f(x)$ you get

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x) &=&\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{x^{2}+1}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{x^{2}-\sqrt{3}x+1}+
\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{x^{2}+\sqrt{3}x+1} \\
&=&\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{x^{2}+1}+\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{\left( 2x-\sqrt{3}
\right) ^{2}+1}+\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{\left( 2x+\sqrt{3}\right) ^{2}+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Since
$$
\int \frac{1}{x^{2}+1}dx=\arctan x
$$
and
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{1}{\left( ax+b\right) ^{2}+1}dx &=&\int \frac{1}{a\left(
u^{2}+1\right) }\,du=\frac{1}{a}\arctan u \\
&=&\frac{1}{a}\arctan \left( ax+b\right), 
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
we have
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{4}+1}{x^{6}+1}dx &=&\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{%
x^{2}+1}dx+\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\left( 2x-\sqrt{3}\right) ^{2}+1}%
dx \\
&&+\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\left( 2x+\sqrt{3}\right) ^{2}+1}dx \\
&=&\frac{2}{3}\arctan 1+\frac{2}{3}\left( \frac{1}{2}\arctan \left( 2-\sqrt{3%
}\right) -\frac{1}{2}\arctan \left( -\sqrt{3}\right) \right)  \\
&&+\frac{2}{3}\left( \frac{1}{2}\arctan \left( 2+\sqrt{3}\right) -\frac{1}{2}%
\arctan \left( \sqrt{3}\right) \right)  \\
&=&\frac{1}{6}\pi +\frac{1}{3}\left( \arctan \left( 2-\sqrt{3}\right)
+\arctan \left( \sqrt{3}\right) \right)  \\
&&+\frac{1}{3}\left( \arctan \left( 2+\sqrt{3}\right) -\arctan \left( \sqrt{3%
}\right) \right)  \\
&=&\frac{1}{6}\pi +\frac{1}{3}\left( \arctan \left( 2-\sqrt{3}\right)
+\arctan \left( 2+\sqrt{3}\right) \right)  \\
&=&\frac{1}{6}\pi +\frac{1}{6}\pi  \\
&=&\frac{1}{3}\pi, 
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

because$^1$
$$
\arctan \left( 2-\sqrt{3}\right) +\arctan \left( 2+\sqrt{3}\right) =\frac{1}{
2}\pi. 
$$

---

$^1$We apply the [arctangent additional formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Arctangent_addition_formula) to $u=2-\sqrt{3}$ and $v=2+\sqrt{3}$

$$
\arctan u+\arctan v=\arctan \frac{u+v}{1-uv}.
$$
Since the product $uv=1$ and $\arctan \left( 2-\sqrt{3}\right) >0,\arctan
\left( 2+\sqrt{3}\right) >0$, we get on the right $\arctan \dfrac{4}{1-1}=
\dfrac{\pi }{2}.$

Answer (score 4):

A not so simple but funny way to compute it :

Denote I the value we are looking for.
With a power series expansion of the integrand, we have
$$ I = 1 + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{36n^2-1} $$
With another series expansion and interversion of the summation, we have
$$ I = 1 + 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty 6^{-2k}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{2k}} $$
We recognize the Dirichlet Eta function evaluated at even integers, so
$$ I = 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2^{2k}-2)\pi^{2k}}{6^{2k}}\frac{|B_{2k}|}{(2k)!} $$
Recognizing the well-known series exansion
$$ 1 - \frac x2 \mathrm{cot} \frac x2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|B_{2k}| x^{2k}}{(2k)!},$$
we have
$$ I = 1 + f(\pi / 3) - 2f(\pi/6), $$ where $f$ is the above function.

The trigonometric computation is not trivial but we eventually find
$$ I = \frac{\pi}{3} $$

Answer (score 3):

First substitute $x=\tan\theta$. Simplify the integrand, noticing that $\sec^2\theta$ is a factor of the original denominator. Use the identity connecting $\tan^2\theta$ and $\cos2\theta$ to write the integrand in terms of $\cos^22\theta$. Now the substitution $t=\tan2\theta$ reduces the integral to a standard form, which proves $\pi/3$ to be the correct answer. This method seems rather roundabout in retrospect, but it requires only natural substitutions, standard trigonometric identities, and straightforward algebraic simplification.

Answer (score 1):

one way is partial fractions on
$$
\frac{x^4+1}{x^6+1}=\frac{(x-e^{\pi i/4})(x-e^{3\pi i/4})(x-e^{5\pi i/4})(x-e^{7\pi i/4})}{(x-e^{\pi i/6})(x-e^{3\pi i/6})(x-e^{5\pi i/6})(x-e^{7\pi i/6})(x-e^{9\pi i/6})(x-e^{11\pi i/6})}
$$
$$
=\frac{(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)}{(x^2+1)(x^2+\sqrt{3}x+1)(x^2-\sqrt{3}x+1)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^4+1}{x^6+1}\,dx\quad\stackrel{\large x\,\mapsto\,\frac{1}{x}}\Longrightarrow\quad I=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^4+1}{x^6+1}\,dx\quad\Longrightarrow\quad I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^4+1}{x^6+1}\,dx$$
Using (proof can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/34351/146687))
$$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^{\large a-1}}{1+x^b}\ dx=\frac{\pi}{b}\csc\left(\frac{a\pi}{b}\right)$$
then
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^4+1}{x^6+1}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\pi}{6}\csc\left(\frac{5\pi}{6}\right)+\frac{\pi}{6}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right]=\frac{\pi}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{x^{4} + 1 \over x^{6} + 1}\,\dd x}
=\half\pars{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{4} + 1 \over x^{6} + 1}\,\dd x
+\int_{0}^{1}{x^{4} + 1 \over x^{6} + 1}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm]&=\half\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{4} + 1 \over x^{6} + 1}\,\dd x
+\int_{\infty}^{1}{1/x^{4} + 1 \over 1/x^{6} + 1}\,\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}}
\\[5mm]&=\half\pars{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{4} + 1 \over x^{6} + 1}\,\dd x
+\int_{1}^{\infty}{x^{4} + 1 \over x^{6} + 1}\,\dd x}
=\half\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{4} + 1 \over x^{6} + 1}\,\dd x
=\color{#66f}{\large%
{1 \over 4}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x^{4} + 1 \over x^{6} + 1}\,\dd x}
\end{align}

> Zeros of $\ds{\quad x^{6} + 1 = 0\quad}$ are given by
>   $\ds{\quad x_{n} = \exp\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\,{\pi \over 6}\,\ic}}$,
>   $\ds{n = 0,1,2,\ldots,5}$, such that:

\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{x^{4} + 1 \over x^{6} + 1}\,\dd x}
={1 \over 4}\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{2}2\pi\ic\lim_{x\ \to\ x_{n}}\bracks{%
\pars{x - x_{n}}\,{x^{4} + 1 \over x^{6} + 1}}
={\pi\ic \over 2}\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{2}{x_{n}^{4} + 1 \over 6x_{n}^{5}}
\\[5mm]&={\pi\ic \over 12}
\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{2}{x_{n}^{2} + x_{n}^{-2} \over x_{n}^{3}}
={\pi\ic \over 12}\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{2}
{2\,\Re\pars{x_{n}^{2}} \over \pars{-1}^{n}\,\ic}
={\pi \over 6}\,\Re\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{2}\pars{-1}^{n}x_{n}^{2}
\\[5mm]&={\pi \over 6}\,\Re\bracks{\exp\pars{{\pi \over 3}\,\ic}
-\exp\pars{\pi\ic} + \exp\pars{{5\pi \over 3}\,\ic}}
={\pi \over 6}\bracks{\half -\pars{-1} + \half}
=\color{#66f}{\large{\pi \over 3}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^1 \frac{x^4+1}{x^6+1} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\frac{(1-y)^2}{(1+y)^2}+1}{\frac{(1-y)^3}{(1+y)^3}+1} \, \sqrt{\frac{1+y}{1-y}} \, \frac{dy}{(1+y)^2} \tag1 \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1+y^2}{1+3y^2} \, \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \\
&= \frac13 \int_0^1 \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} + \frac23 \int_0^1 \frac{dy}{\left(1+3y^2\right) \sqrt{1-y^2}} \tag2 \\
&= \frac13 \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 dz + \frac23 \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \frac{dz}{1+3\sin^2z} \tag3 \\
&= \frac13 \cdot \frac\pi2 + \frac23 \cdot \frac\pi4 = \boxed{\frac\pi3} \tag4
\end{align*}$$

---

- $(1)$ Substitute $x = \sqrt{\dfrac{1-y}{1+y}}$
- $(2)$ Partial fractions
- $(3)$ Substitute $y=\sin z$
- $(4)$ Second integral:
  $$\int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \frac{dz}{1+3\sin^2z} \, dz = \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \frac{\sec^2z}{1+4\tan^2z} \, dz = \frac12 \lim_{z\to\tfrac\pi2^-} \arctan\left(2\tan z\right)$$