# Real VS Complex for integrals: $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1 + x^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

The integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1 + x^4} = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}$$
can be evaluated both by a complex method (residues) and by a
real method (partial fraction decomposition).
The complex method works also for the integral 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1 + x^3} = \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}$$
but partial fraction decomposition does not give convergent integrals. I would like to know if there is some real method for evaluating this last integral.

Answer (score 12):

Make the substitution $x = \frac{1}{t}$ and you get

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t}{1+t^3} \text{d}t$$

Write the one you want as

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+t^3} \text{d}t$$

Now you can add both and cancel that pesky $1+t$ factor.

btw, a straightforward approach using partial fractions also works.

You consider

$$F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{1+t^3} \text{d}t$$

Using partial fractions you can find that (I used Wolfram Alpha, I admit)

$$F(x) = \frac{1}{6}\left(2\log(x+1) - \log(x^2 - x -1) + 2\sqrt{3} \arctan\left(\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right) + \frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{3}}$$

Now as $x \to \infty$, we have that $2\log(x+1) - \log(x^2 - x + 1) \to 0$ .

Comment: See this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34351/simpler-way-to-compute-a-definite-integral-without-resorting-to-partial-fraction/34362#34362 to see that you can also evaluate the integral in that question to find your answer here, and then apply the other answers to that question (in particular, Eric's answer(s)).

Comment: Thank you Aryabhata. This is a very elegant way of evaluation by reducing it to the $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2 - x + 1}$.

Comment: @Martin: You are welcome. I have added another method, which does use partial fractions.

Answer (score 6):

Note that for $a > 0$, $$\int_0^N \frac{1}{x+a}\ dx = \ln(N+a) - \ln(a) = \ln(N) - \ln(a) + o(1)\  \text{as} \ N \to \infty$$ while
$$\eqalign{\int_0^N \frac{x+a}{(x+a)^2 + b^2}\ dx &= \frac{1}{2} \left(\ln((N+a)^2+b^2) - \ln(a^2+b^2)\right)\cr &= \ln(N) - \ln(a^2+b^2) + o(1) \  \text{as} \ N \to \infty\cr}$$
and (if $b > 0$)
$$ \eqalign{\int_0^N \frac{1}{(x+a)^2+b^2}\ dx = \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{N+a}{b}\right) - \arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{b} = \frac{\pi}{2b} - \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}{b} + o(1)
 \  \text{as} \ N \to \infty\cr}$$
In particular, from the partial fraction decomposition
$$ \frac{1}{1+x^3} = \frac{1/3}{x+1} + \frac{(2-x)/3}{x^2 - x + 1} = \frac{1/3}{x+1} +
\frac{1/2}{(x-1/2)^2+3/4} - \frac{(x-1/2)/3}{(x-1/2)^2 + 3/4}$$
you get
$$ \int_0^N \frac{1}{1+x^3} \ dx = \frac{\ln(N) - \ln(1))}{3} + \frac{\pi/2 + \arctan(1/\sqrt{3})}{\sqrt{3}} - \frac{\ln(N) - \ln((1/2)^2 + 3/4)}{3}  + o(1)$$
i.e.
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^3} \ dx = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{\arctan(1/\sqrt{3})}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{2 \pi}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: Thank you Robert. Nice solution by taking asymptotics. Little typo: in the last integral the upper bound is $\infty$

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

For what is worth:

Your integral evaluates in terms of the sine function:

$$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^a}=\frac{\pi}{a}\sec\frac{\pi}{a}$$

refer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-of-integral) and the link in it.

Answer (score 2):

> *I would like to know if there is some real method for evaluating this last integral.*

Actually, all integrals of the form $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{1+x^m}dx$ can be solved by substituting $t=\dfrac1{1+x^m}$ , and then recognizing the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral, which can be written as a product of [gamma functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). Then we use the [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) in order to finally arrive at the desired result, $I=\dfrac\pi m\cdot\csc\left[(n+1)\dfrac\pi m\right]$ — See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-of-integral) for more information.