# How to evaluate  $\int_0^\infty {x \over 1 + x^5} \;dx $?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simpler way to compute a definite integral without resorting to partial fractions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34351/simpler-way-to-compute-a-definite-integral-without-resorting-to-partial-fraction)

How to evaluate the following integral using complex method?
$$\int_0^\infty {x \over 1 + x^5} \;dx $$

Comment: This question is a solved by [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/34761/6075), which evaluates the integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{1+x^\beta}dx.$$  You are looking at the case $\alpha=2$ and $\beta =5$. The value of your integral is then $$\frac{\pi}{5\sin(2\pi/5)}.$$

Comment: Thanks @EricNaslund I got the answer.