# An Edwards Integral

Tags: integration

This is from Edwards Classic Treatise on the Integral Calculus, Vol 1, p167 and appears quite simple but several pages later I get stuck on partial fraction decomposition.

Show that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^5} dx = \frac{4\pi}{5\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}$$

Comment: See [this](http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/13-1994458-6868513-571438/integral%20of%20(1%20+%20x%5E5)%5E(-1).pdf) for essentially the same thing, in all its gory details when solved using only U.S. calculus 2 methods.

Comment: Wow ! No wonder I have several pages of A4 scribbles. Thank you

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189558/how-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-x-over-1-x5-dx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the substitution $u=x^5$ gives
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^5}\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac15\int_0^\infty\frac{u^{-3/5}}{1+u}\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac15B\left(\frac25,\frac35\right)\\
&=\frac15\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac25\right)\Gamma\left(\frac35\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac25+\frac35\right)}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac25\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac25\right)}5\\
&=\frac{\pi}{5\sin{\left(\frac{2\pi}5\right)}}\\
&=\frac{4\pi}{5\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}\\
\end{align}$$
Where I have used two representations of the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties), [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) and then the value of $\sin{(2\pi/5)}$ which is calculated [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi5.html).