# How to evaluate $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty {e^{ax} \over 1 +e^x } \; dx $

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possibility to simplify $\sum\limits_{k =  - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{a + k}} = \frac{\pi }{{\sin \pi a}}} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110494/possibility-to-simplify-sum-limits-k-infty-infty-frac-left)

Given that $0 < a < 1$ how to evaluate by the method of residues
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty {e^{ax} \over 1 +e^x } \; dx $$

Comment: In particular, see Argon's answer to that question.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff how did you change the sum into integral?

Comment: I explain it in detail in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substituting $u=e^x$, so that $dx = \dfrac{du}{u}$, the integral becomes

$$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{u^{a-1}}{1+u}du$$

How might you solve this? You've tagged the question as homework, so I'll leave it here for now, but if you're still stuck, post in the comments.

Comment: does [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34351/simpler-way-to-compute-a-definite-integral-without-resorting-to-partial-fraction/34761#34761) method work when $0<a<1$ ? this needs a little editing and picture of contour is missing

Comment: @testuser: Yes.

Comment: I must be an idiot :(((

Comment: @testuser: Possible, but unlikely! Just follow through that solution with $b=1$ all the way through. [Or work it out yourself $-$ it's not too hard using fairly standard complex methods.]

Comment: yeah the answer is $ \pi \over \sin (a \pi )$

Answer (score 3):

Recalling the $\beta$ function,

$$ \beta( n,m ) = \int_{0}^{1} u^{n-1}\,(1-u)^{m-1}\, du = \frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(m)}{\Gamma(m+n)} \,.$$

Using the substitution $ 1+u=\frac{1}{t} $ casts $ \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{u^{a-1}}{1+u}du $ in terms of the $\beta$ function,

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{u^{a-1}}{1+u}du = \int _{0}^{1}\!{t}^{-a} \left( 1-t \right) ^{a-1}{dt} =\Gamma(a)\Gamma(1-a) = \frac{\pi}{\sin (a \pi )} \,. $$

Comment: @Downvoter:I do not know what you are downvoting for. I gave a way to evaluate the integral in a way different from the complex techniques.