# change of variables in contour integration problem

Tags: complex-analysis

On this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/282675/65097, we see that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \: \frac{t^2}{t^4+1} dt = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+1} dx$$

from the change of variables $x = t^2$.

This is a dumb question but, how did the bounds change from $0$ to $\infty$ becoming $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you change variables, you have to halve the interval:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt  \: \frac{t^2}{t^4+1} = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} dt \: \frac{t^2}{t^4+1}$$

Now change variables: $t = \sqrt{x}$, $dt = \frac{dx}{2 \sqrt{x}}$

The result follows.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the act of changing of variables (in your answer) caused the bounds to change.

Comment: @aa: if this answer is useful, you can *upvote* it by clicking on the arrow pointing up next to it. If this answers your question best, you can *accept* it by clicking on the check mark next to it.