# Solving the integral of $\frac {dx} {1+x^3}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

> Compute integral $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^3}$$.

I used the formula from complex variables by fisher (2.6 formula (9)) that $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^a}=\frac {\pi} {a\sin(\pi/a)}$$ This means $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^3}=\frac {\pi} {3\sin(\pi/3)}$$ Is that simply the answer or do I need to expand it to find all concrete values?

Additionally, from this answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358262/solving-the-improper-integral-int-0-infty-fracdx1x3), the improper integral gives a different result:

$$-\frac{1}{6} \ln |x^2-x+1|+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \arctan\left(\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{1}{3}\ln|x+1|$$

is this result equal to the one I got above?

Comment: It's not that it gave a different result. You simply calculated the indefinite integral $F(x) = \int 1/1+x^3\,dx$. What you need to do now is consider $\lim_{b\to\infty} F(b) - F(0)$ to match the two different answers.

Comment: oh so the other answer is an indefinite integral--what i got is a simple definite integral? but if i got the definite integral, why do i still need to consider the limit? please forgive me but I am new to complex integral so please guide me a bit on calculating the limit

Comment: Several answers in the link you gave give a value for the integral of $\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}.\ $ Also, $\ \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.\ $ Therefore the answer your formula gives is $\large{\frac{\pi}{3\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) } = \frac{\pi}{3\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} } = \frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}}.\ $ This matches the other answers, so yes, you can be confident that that is the correct answer. I'm not sure what you mean by, " or do I need to expand it to find all concrete values?"

Comment: understood thank you my confusion is basically "why is $\frac {\pi} {3sin(\pi/3)}$ not the final answer? and why do we need to proceed to calculate the lim of F(b)-f(0)"? or i am confused and $\frac {\pi} {3sin(\pi/3)}$ is the final answer--it is just the quesiton is literally one step and seemed too easy...

Comment: @jamesblack perhaps the question wanted you to find this answer without consulting any tables or integral solvers. Would you like me to show how to find the answer for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Next, simplify
$$
F(x)=-\frac{1}{6}\ln|x^2-x+1|+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan{\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}}+\frac{1}{3}\ln|x+1|
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{1}{3}\ln|x+1|-\frac{1}{3}\ln\sqrt{|x^2-x+1|}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{1}{3}\ln\left(\frac{|x+1|}{\sqrt{|x^2-x+1|}}\right).
$$
Then
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^3}=\lim_{X\rightarrow\infty}F(X)-F(0).$$
Compute the limit, and you are done.