# Сalculate the integral PV $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^\alpha(x-a)}dx.$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-principal-value

> Сalculate the integral
> $$ \mathrm{PV}\hspace{-0.5ex}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^\alpha(x-a)}, $$
> where $0<\alpha <1$ and $a>0$.

So we have simple poles $z = 0$ and $z = a$; We can build contour [like in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373164/contour-integration-int-0-infty-frac1xa1-x-dx-for-0a1) to exclude these points.

But for example, in the general case $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{R(x)}{x^\alpha} \, dx$, where $R(x)$ is a rational function without poles in $\mathbb{R}$ we can apply something like that:<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCapK.jpg)</sup>

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{\substack{\varepsilon \to 0 \\ R \to \infty}} \int_{\partial\mathcal{D}_{R,\varepsilon}} \frac{R(z)}{z^{\alpha}} \, dz
= 2\pi i \cdot \sum_k \mathop{\underset{\substack{z=z_k \\ z_k \neq 0}}{\mathrm{Res}}} \frac{R(z)}{z^{\alpha}} \\
&\hspace{3ex}= \lim_{\substack{\varepsilon \to 0 \\ R \to \infty}} \Biggl[ \, 
\underbrace{\int_{\partial\mathcal{C}_{\varepsilon}} \frac{R(z)}{z^{\alpha}} \, dz}_{\to 0 \text{ as } \varepsilon \to 0}
+ \int_{[\varepsilon, R]^+} \frac{R(z)}{z^{\alpha}} \, dz
+ \underbrace{\int_{\partial\mathcal{C}_{R}} \frac{R(z)}{z^{\alpha}} \, dz}_{\to 0 \text{ as } R \to \infty}
+ \int_{[R, \varepsilon]^-} \frac{R(z)}{z^{\alpha}} \, dz \,\Biggr] \\
&\hspace{3ex}= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{R(x)}{x^{\alpha}} \, dx
+ \int_{\infty}^{0} \frac{R(x)}{x^{\alpha}e^{2\pi \alpha i}} \, dx \\
&\hspace{3ex}= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{R(x)}{x^{\alpha}} \, dx
- \biggl( \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{R(x)}{x^{\alpha}e^{2\pi \alpha i}} \, dx \biggr) e^{-2\pi \alpha i} \\[1ex]
&\hspace{3ex}= I - I e^{-2\pi \alpha i}
= \bigl(1 - e^{-2\pi \alpha i}\bigr) I \\[2ex]
&\hspace{3ex}\implies \ \bbox[border:1px black solid;padding:5px;]{I = \frac{2\pi i}{1 - e^{-2\pi \alpha i}} \sum_k \mathop{\underset{\substack{z=z_k \\ z_k \neq 0}}{\mathrm{Res}}} \frac{R(z)}{z^{\alpha}}}
\end{align*}

So, my question: How can I avoid long calculations from [first answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373164/contour-integration-int-0-infty-frac1xa1-x-dx-for-0a1).

Сan I apply this theorem for my case? (For example use this<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFsV8.png)</sup> instead of $2\pi i \mathop{\underset{z=z_k}{\mathrm{Res}}} \frac{R(z)}{z^\alpha}$ from my calculation above.)

> **Theorem 9.13.** Suppose $f(z)$ has a **simple** pole at $z_0$. Let $C_r$ be the semicircle $\gamma(\theta) = z_0 + r\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}$, with $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$. Then
> $$\lim_{r \to 0} \int_{C_r} f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z = \pi i \operatorname{Res} (f, z_0). $$

Comment: What is the easiest way to calculate this integral? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following result may be useful:

> **Lemma.** Let $f$ be a holomorphic function defined on an open set $U$ containing the interval $(0, \infty)$ such that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{|f(x)|}{1+x} \, \mathrm{d}x < \infty$. Then for any $a > 0$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> \mathrm{PV}\hspace{-0.5ex}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x-a} \, \mathrm{d}x
> &= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x-a-i\varepsilon} \, \mathrm{d}x - \pi i f(a) \\
> &= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x-a+i\varepsilon} \, \mathrm{d}x + \pi i f(a).
> \end{align*}

Using this lemma and OP's computation, we have

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{PV}\hspace{-0.5ex}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}(x-a)} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}(x-a-i\varepsilon)} \, \mathrm{d}x - \frac{\pi i}{a^{\alpha}} \tag{by lemma} \\
&= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \frac{2\pi i}{1-e^{-2\pi\alpha i}} \cdot \frac{1}{(a+i\varepsilon)^{\alpha}} - \frac{\pi i}{a^{\alpha}} \tag{by OP} \\
&= \frac{2\pi i}{1-e^{-2\pi\alpha i}} \cdot \frac{1}{a^{\alpha}} - \frac{\pi i}{a^{\alpha}} \\
&= \frac{\pi \cot(\pi \alpha)}{a^{\alpha}}.
\end{align*}

---

*Proof of Lemma.* Let $\delta > 0$ be sufficiently small so that the closed disk $\{z\in\mathbb{C} : |z-a|\leq\delta\}$ is contained in $U$, and consider the contour $(0, a-\delta) \cup \gamma_{\delta} \cup (a+\delta, \infty)$ as below:

[image: contour]

Then by the [Cauchy integration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem), we can deform the integral path $(0, \infty)$ into the above contour without changing the value of the integral:

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x-a-i\varepsilon} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{0}^{a-\delta} \frac{f(x)}{x-a-i\varepsilon} \, \mathrm{d}x
+ \int_{\gamma_{\delta}} \frac{f(z)}{z-a-i\varepsilon} \, \mathrm{d}z
+ \int_{a+\delta}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x-a-i\varepsilon} \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Letting $\varepsilon \to 0^+$ and then $\delta \to 0^+$, and then applying the dominated convergence theorem and Theorem 9.13 in OP, we get

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x-a-i\varepsilon} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\quad= \int_{0}^{a-\delta} \frac{f(x)}{x-a} \, \mathrm{d}x
+ \int_{\gamma_{\delta}} \frac{f(z)}{z-a} \, \mathrm{d}z
+ \int_{a+\delta}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x-a} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\quad\to \mathrm{PV}\hspace{-0.5ex}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x-a} \, \mathrm{d}x + \pi i f(a)
\qquad \text{as } \delta \to 0^+.
\end{align*}

This proves the first part of the desired equality. The second part can be proved in a similar manner.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done without any contour integrals with some clever manipulations. It's not too hard to show that
$$
\mathrm{PV}\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^\alpha (x-a)} = \frac{1}{a^\alpha}\mathrm{PV}\int_0^\infty \frac{du}{u^\alpha (u-1)} =\frac{1}{\alpha^a}\int_0^{1}\frac{u^{\alpha-1}-u^{-\alpha}}{1-u}du.
$$
We can then use this integral representation of the digamma function,
$$
\psi(z) = \frac{d}{dz}\ln\Gamma(z) = \int_0^1\left(\frac{u^{z-1}}{u-1}-\log u\right)du,
$$
to compute the integral as
$$
\int_0^{1}\frac{u^{\alpha-1}-u^{-\alpha}}{1-u}du= \psi(1-\alpha)-\psi(\alpha) = -\frac{d}{d\alpha}\ln\left[\Gamma(1-\alpha)\Gamma(\alpha)\right] = -\frac{d}{d\alpha}\ln[\pi\csc(\pi \alpha)] = \pi\cot(\pi\alpha)
$$
which gives
$$
\mathrm{PV}\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^\alpha (x-a)} =\frac{\pi\cot(\pi\alpha)}{\alpha^a}
$$