# Integration of $\int_0^\infty \sqrt x e^{-x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am having a really hard time trying to figure out what to do with this. I feel like I've tried everything but I'm obviously missing something. Any suggestions?

$$\int_0^\infty \sqrt x\ e^{-x^2}\ dx$$

These are all the techniques I have learned in class/can choose from: integration by parts, u-substitution, partial fractions, trig substitution. I don't know anything about the gamma function and am not allowed to use it.

Comment: What did you try? Are you familiar with the gamma function?

Comment: Try a substitution of $u=\sqrt x$. Realize a gamma integral once you have done that.

Comment: OP does not know what the gamma function is.

Comment: @G.DineshNathan check the question, he specifically says he cannot use the gamma function.

Comment: see http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf for new tricks...

Comment: @G.DineshNathan Also, you probably meant $u = x^2$, as $u = \sqrt{x}$ would make the exponent $u^4$.

Comment: I doubt there is a way to solve this without the Gamma function.

Comment: The answer is $\Gamma(3/4)/2$, and this can't be expressed using "elementary" functions.  So if he can't use the Gamma function he's out of luck.  Unless perhaps the question was whether this converges, rather than find the value?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Or perhaps he's expected to express the answer as a series?

Comment: If you have learned about infinite series, you an express this as such a series and integrate term by term. Other than that, there is no way that I know of to evaluate this integral.

Comment: @AlfredYerger: Which series did you have in mind?

Comment: You can find a series for $e^{-x^{2}}$ and multiply through.

Comment: If you mean a Taylor series, the terms will not have finite integrals from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Maybe he was actually given $\int_0^\infty\sqrt x e^{-x^3}\,dx$? _That_ one can be converted into a Gaussian integral, and this site features many clever, elementary evaluations of it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $~t=x^{^\tfrac32}.~$ Then $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\sqrt x~e^{-x^2}~dx=\frac23\int_0^\infty\exp\bigg(-t^{^\tfrac43}\bigg)~dt=\frac23\cdot\bigg(\frac34\bigg)!~$ This is based on

the fact that $n!=\mathcal G\bigg(\dfrac1n\bigg)$, where $\mathcal G(n)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty~e^{-t^n}~dt.~$ See [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) for more details.

---

> *I don't know anything about the gamma function and am not allowed to use it.*

You can't *not* use it, since, as you can clearly see, there is no alternate way of expressing the result.