# complex variable integral using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am asked to calculate a complex integral. how to compute $\displaystyle \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^4}{1+x^8}dx$ with residue theorem?

Comment: What's troubling you?

Comment: compute the residues

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/37372/123277).

Comment: This doesn't look like a duplicate to me.  The other question doesn't specify that it is to be done by using the residue theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints that might help you along the way:

Start off by writing the expression as
$$
\oint_{C} \frac{z^4}{1 + z^8}dz
$$
where $C$ is the contour. Now find the residues:
$$
1 + z_n^8 = 0, z_n \in C
$$
Then the integral value is
$$
2 \pi i \sum Res_{z=z_n}f(z)
$$

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in an alternative method using the Beta function. Note that the integrand is even, so
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^4}{1+x^8}dx
&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^4}{1+x^8}dx\\
\end{align}
Use the substitution $x=u^{1/8}$, then $dx=\frac{1}{8}u^{-7/8}du$. The integral becomes
\begin{align}
2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^4}{1+x^8}dx
&=\frac{1}{4}{\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{u^{-3/8}}{1+u}du}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\int^{1}_{0}\frac{(\frac{y}{1-y})^{-3/8}}{1+\frac{y}{1-y}}\frac{dy}{(1-y)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\int^{1}_{0}y^{-3/8}(1-y)^{-5/8}dy\\
&=\frac{1}{4}B(5/8,\ 3/8)\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(5/8)\ \Gamma(3/8)}{4\ \Gamma(1)}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}\csc{\frac{3\pi}{8}}
\end{align}
I have made use of  the [definition of the Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and [Euler's Reflection Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula).

If you prefer a complex analysis approach, the poles are at
\begin{align}
z=e^{i (2n+1)\pi /8}, \ n\in\mathbb{Z}, \ 0\le n \le 7
\end{align}
Figure out which singularities lie in your contour and proceed with the integration.

Comment: can you explain more the part being bracketed?

Comment: Sure. I have updated my answer to make it more detailed.