# Prove $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{k-1} + x^{-k-1}}{x^a + x^{-a}}dx = \frac{\pi}{a \cos(\frac{\pi k}{2a})}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I need help in proving this identity

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{k-1} + x^{-k-1}}{x^a + x^{-a}}dx = \frac{\pi}{a \cos(\frac{\pi k}{2a})}$$

for $0<k<a.$ It might be done using residues, but I don't know which contour to choose.

Comment: *It might be done using residues* - Indeed, it might... But I personally would prefer to rewrite the integral in terms of the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), and then employ the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=e^u$; then the integral is equal to

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} du\, \frac{\cosh{k u}}{\cosh{a u}}  $$

This integral may be evaluated by considering the following contour integral

$$\oint_C dz \, \frac{\cosh{k z}}{\cosh{a z}}  $$

where $C$ is the rectangle having vertices $-R$, $R$, $R+i \pi/a$, and $-R+i \pi/a$.  The contour integral is equal to

$$\int_{-R}^R dx \,   \frac{\cosh{k x}}{\cosh{a x}} + i \int_0^{\pi/a} dy \, \frac{\cosh{k (R+i y)}}{\cosh{a (R+i y)}} \\ +  \int_{-R}^R dx \,  \frac{\cosh{[k (x+i \pi/a)]}}{\cosh{a x}}+i \int_{\pi/a}^0 dy \, \frac{\cosh{k (-R+i y)}}{\cosh{a (-R+i y)}}$$

Note that, because $0 \lt k \lt a$, the second and fourth integrals vanish as $R \to \infty$.  Thus, in this limit, the contour integral is equal to

$$[1+ \cos{(\pi k/a)} ]\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \,  \frac{\cosh{k x}}{\cosh{a x}} -i \sin{(\pi k/a)} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \,  \frac{\sinh{k x}}{\cosh{a x}} $$

Note that the second integral is zero because it is an odd integral over a symmetric interval.

By the residue theorem, the contour integral is also equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue of the integrand at $z=i \pi/(2 a)$, or $(2 \pi/a) \, \cos{[\pi k/(2 a)]} $.  The result is therefore

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \,  \frac{\cosh{k x}}{\cosh{a x}} = \frac{\pi}{a} \frac{2 \cos{[\pi k/(2 a)]}}{1+ \cos{(\pi k/a)}} = \frac{\pi}{a} \sec{\left (\frac{\pi k}{2 a} \right )} $$

as was to be shown.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And now I'll delete the comment to reduce clutter.

Comment: @Ron Gordon. Thanks, great evaluation! At one point I'm still a bit confused: Shouldn't the third integral of the contour integral from $-R$ to $R$ have a negative sign (due to counterclockwise path)? But then we'd have: $[1 - \cos(\pi k/a) {...} ]$ and $\frac{\pi}{a} \frac{2 \cos{[\pi k/(2 a)]}}{1- \cos{(\pi k/a)}}$, and get a different result ... where am I wrong?

Comment: @M_a_t: sorry, I combined two steps into one.  You end up getting, in the third integral, $\cosh{(a x+i \pi)} = -\cosh{(a x)}$.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, how could I have overseen that?! Now all is clear! Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @RonGordon An alternative proof using residues is presented below.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
I &= \int^\infty_0 \frac{x^{k - 1} + x^{-kn - 1}}{x^a + x^{-a}} \, dx\\
&= \int^\infty_0 \frac{x^{k - 1} + x^{-k - 1}}{x^{-a} (x^{2a} + 1)} \, dx\\
&= \int^\infty_0 \frac{x^{k + a -1} + x^{a - k - 1}}{x^{2a} + 1} \, dx
\end{align*}
Let $t = x^{2a}, x = t^{\frac{1}{2a}}, dx = \frac{1}{2a} t^{\frac{1 - 2a}{2a}} \, dt$ while the limits of integration remain unchanged. Thus
\begin{align*}
I &= \int^\infty_0 \frac{t^{\frac{k + a - 1}{2a}} + t^{\frac{a - k - 1}{2a}}}{1 + t} \cdot \frac{1}{2a} t^{\frac{1 - 2a}{2a}} \, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2a} \int^\infty_0 \int^\infty_0 \frac{t^{\frac{k - a}{2a}} + t^{\frac{-a-k}{2a}}}{1 + t} \, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2a} \int^\infty_0 \frac{t^{\frac{k + a}{2a} - 1}}{(1 + t)^{\frac{k + a}{2a} + \frac{a - k}{2a}}} \, dt + \frac{1}{2a} \int^\infty_0 \frac{t^{\frac{a - k}{2a} - 1}}{(1 + t)^{\frac{a - k}{2a} + \frac{k + a}{2a}}} \, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2a} \mbox{B} \left (\frac{k + a}{2a}, \frac{a - k}{2a} \right ) + \frac{1}{2a} \mbox{B} \left (\frac{k - a}{2a}, \frac{a + k}{2a} \right )
\end{align*}
Here $\displaystyle{\mbox{B} (m,n)}$ is the beta function. Since $\mbox{B}(m,n) = \mbox{B}(n,m)$ we have
\begin{align*}
I &= \frac{1}{a} \mbox{B} \left (\frac{k + a}{2a}, \frac{a - k}{2a} \right )\\ 
&= \frac{1}{a} \cdot \frac{\Gamma \left (\frac{k + a}{2a} \right ) \Gamma \left (\frac{a - k}{2a} \right )}{\Gamma \left (\frac{k + a}{2a} + \frac{a - k}{2a} \right )}, \quad \mbox{since} \,\, \mbox{B}(m,n) = \frac{\Gamma (m) \Gamma (n)}{\Gamma (m + n)}\\
&= \frac{1}{a} \Gamma \left (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{k}{2a} \right ) \Gamma \left (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{k}{2a} \right ), \quad \mbox{since} \,\, \Gamma (1) = 1\\
&= \frac{\pi}{a \cos \left (\frac{k\pi}{2} \right )}
\end{align*}
as required to show. Note in the last line the following reflection formula for the gamma function has been used
$$\Gamma \left (\frac{1}{2} + x \right ) \Gamma \left (\frac{1}{2} - x \right ) = \frac{\pi}{\cos (x \pi)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34351/simpler-way-to-compute-a-definite-integral-without-resorting-to-partial-fraction/37372#37372) post, we know that
$$ \int_0^\infty\frac{u^{\alpha-1}}{1+u^\beta}dx=\frac{\pi}{\beta\sin(\frac{\pi\alpha}{\beta})}.$$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{k-1} + x^{-k-1}}{x^a + x^{-a}}dx &=&
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{a+k-1}}{1 + x^{2a}}dx+\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{a-k-1}}{1 + x^{2a}}dx\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{2a\sin(\frac{(a+k-1)\pi}{2a})}+\frac{\pi}{2a\sin(\frac{(a-k-1)\pi}{2a})}\\
&=& \frac{\pi}{a \cos(\frac{\pi k}{2a})}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we seek to evaluate

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{k-1}+x^{-k-1}}{x^a+x^{-a}} dx$$

where  $0\lt  k \lt  a$  directly  using  residues without  additional
substitutions.

We  evaluate this  for  $a$ rational  so that  $a=p/q$  and extend  by
continuity  to $a$  real.  We  take $p$  and $q$ in lowest terms.

We use a pizza  slice contour of radius $R$ with  the branch cut of
the  logarithm on  the positive  real axis  and argument  from $0$  to
$2\pi.$ Moreover we  treat the two summands $J_1$  and $J_2$ appearing
in the numerator in turn.

We set the sloped component of the slice at angle $\pi q/p$ 
and we obtain with $x$ real
$$(x\exp(\pi i q/p))^a
= \exp(a\log(x\exp(\pi i q/p)))
\\= \exp(a\log x + \pi i) = -x^a$$

and
$$(x\exp(\pi i q/p))^{-a}
= \exp(-a\log(x\exp(\pi i q/p)))
\\= \exp(-a\log x - \pi i) = -x^{-a}.$$

We also have on the sloped segment for $J_1$
$$(x\exp(\pi i q/p))^{k-1}
= \exp((k-1)\log(x\exp(\pi i q/p)))
\\ = x^{k-1} \exp(\pi i q (k-1)/p)$$

and for $J_2$

$$(x\exp(\pi i q/p))^{-k-1}
= \exp((-k-1)\log(x\exp(\pi i q/p)))
\\ = x^{-k-1} \exp(\pi i q (-k-1)/p).$$

Now by ML on the curved segment of radius $R$ of $J_1$ we get the bound
$$\pi q/p \times R \times \frac{R^{k-1}}{R^a-R^{-a}}
\rightarrow 0$$
as $R\rightarrow\infty$ because $k \lt a.$

Similarly for $J_2$ we obtain
$$\pi q/p \times R \times \frac{R^{-k-1}}{R^a-R^{-a}}
\rightarrow 0$$
as $R\rightarrow\infty$ as well.

We  also need  to  apply  ML on  the  circular indentation  segment
of radius $\epsilon$ excluding the origin where we get for $J_1$
with $\epsilon$ going to zero

$$\pi q/p \times \epsilon \times 
\frac{\epsilon^{k-1}}{(1/\epsilon)^a-\epsilon^{a}}
\rightarrow 0$$

as  $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$  because  the numerator  vanishes and  the
first term in the denominator dominates, going to infinity.

Similarly for $J_2$ we obtain
$$\pi q/p \times \epsilon \times 
\frac{\epsilon^{-k-1}}{(1/\epsilon)^a-\epsilon^{a}}
\rightarrow 0$$

as $\epsilon\rightarrow  0$ because the  numerator is $(1/\epsilon)^k$
and the denominator is $(1/\epsilon)^a$ and $k\lt a.$

The zeros of $x^a + x^{-a} = x^{-a} (x^{2a}+1)$
and hence the poles
are at $$\rho_m = \exp((2\pi i m + \pi i) /(2p/q))
= \exp(\pi i m q/p + \pi i q/2/p).$$

The first pole at $\rho_0 = \exp(\pi i q/2/p)$
is inside the slice but the next one $\rho_1 = \exp(3\pi i q/2/p)$
is outside the slice already.

We  have periodicity  when  $m$ is  a multiple  of  $2p$ and  $\rho_0$
re-appears so $\rho_0$ is in fact the only pole we have to consider.
(Here we have used the fact that $p/q$ is in lowest terms.)

We get the following residue for $J_1$:

$$\frac{\rho_0^{k-1}}{a\rho_0^{a-1}-a\rho_0^{-a-1}}
= \frac{\rho_0^{k}}{a\rho_0^{a}-a\rho_0^{-a}}
= \frac{\rho_0^{k}}{a\rho_0^{a}+a\rho_0^{a}}
= \frac{1}{2a} \rho_0^{k-a}
= - \frac{i}{2a} \rho_0^{k}.$$

Similarly we get for $J_2$
$$\frac{\rho_0^{-k-1}}{a\rho_0^{a-1}-a\rho_0^{-a-1}}
= \frac{\rho_0^{-k}}{a\rho_0^{a}-a\rho_0^{-a}}
= \frac{\rho_0^{-k}}{a\rho_0^{a}+a\rho_0^{a}}
= \frac{1}{2a} \rho_0^{-k-a}
= - \frac{i}{2a} \rho_0^{-k}.$$

Collecting everything we have

$$J_1(1+\rho_0^{2k})  = - 2\pi i \frac{i}{2a} \rho_0^{k}
\quad\text{or}\quad
J_1 = \frac{\pi}{a} \frac{\rho_0^k}{1+\rho_0^{2k}}
= \frac{\pi}{a} \frac{1}{\rho_0^{-k}+\rho_0^{k}} $$

and
$$J_2(1+\rho_0^{-2k}) = - 2\pi i \frac{i}{2a} \rho_0^{-k}
\quad\text{or}\quad
J_2 = \frac{\pi}{a} \frac{\rho_0^{-k}}{1+\rho_0^{-2k}}
= \frac{\pi}{a} \frac{1}{\rho_0^k+\rho_0^{-k}}$$

Now we have
$$\frac{1}{\rho_0^k+\rho_0^{-k}}
= \frac{1}{\exp(\pi i k/a/2) + \exp(-\pi i k/a/2)}
= \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\cos(\pi k/a/2)}.$$

Adding these yields the end result

$$\frac{\pi}{a} \frac{1}{\cos(\pi k/a/2)}.$$

**Important remark.** When verifying this computation with a CAS we
need to re-define the logarithm  and the power function, e.g. in Maple
we use

```
LOG :=
proc(z)
    local w;

    w := log(z);

    if evalf(Im(w)) < 0 then
        w := w + 2*Pi*I;
    fi;

    w;
end;

POW := (v, q) -> exp(q*LOG(v));


Q :=
proc(p, q, k)
    local a, cont, rho, res;

    a := p/q;

    rho := exp(Pi*I/a/2);
    res := POW(rho, k)/(a*POW(rho, a)-a*POW(rho, -a));
    # res := POW(rho, k-a)/2/a;

    2*Pi*I*res/(1 + exp(I*Pi/a*k));
    # 2*Pi*I*res/(1 + rho^(2*k));
end;

QQ := (p, q, k) -> 
int(x^(k-1)/(x^(p/q) + x^(-p/q)), x=0..infinity);
```

Of course  all the  powers of  $\rho_0$ that appear  in the  above are
calculated with this branch of the logarithm.

**Observation.** The  angle $\pi q/p$  is taken modulo  $2\pi$ when
defining the  contour (which  does not make  multiple turns)  and when
computing the bounds on the two arcs.

**Highly significant  addendum.** It so happens I  missed a crucial
fact when I wrote the above,  namely that *the branch of the logarithm
to use  depends on  the value of  $a$*!  We  must pick a  branch where
$$\rho_0^{2a}  = -1$$  holds, otherwise  the computation  will  not go
through. E.g. suppose you want to solve the equation $\sqrt{x}+1 = 0.$
The branch  to choose here  must produce $-1$  as the root of  $1$. We
have  for all  branches  that $\sqrt{x}  =  \exp(1/2\log(x)).$ Now  if
$\log(1) = 2\pi i$ we  get the desired result.  Apply this observation
to obtain the following modified Maple routine:

```
LOG :=
proc(z, sheet)
    local w;

    w := log(z);

    if evalf(Im(w)) < 0 then
        w := w + 2*Pi*I;
    fi;

    w + sheet*2*Pi*I;
end;

POW := (v, q, sheet) -> exp(q*LOG(v, sheet));


Q :=
proc(p, q, k)
    local a, cont, rho, res, sheet, val;

    a := p/q;

    rho := exp(Pi*I/a/2);

    for sheet from 0 to 2*q-1 do
        val := 2*a*Im(LOG(rho, sheet))/Pi;

        if type(val, odd) then
            break;
        fi;
    od;

    if sheet = 2*q then return FAIL fi;

    res := 
    POW(rho, k, sheet)/
    (a*POW(rho, a, sheet)-a*POW(rho, -a, sheet));
    # res := POW(rho, k-a)/2/a;

    [sheet, 2*Pi*I*res/(1 + exp(I*Pi/a*k))];
    # 2*Pi*I*res/(1 + rho^(2*k));
end;

QQ := (p, q, k) ->
int(x^(k-1)/(x^(p/q) + x^(-p/q)), x=0..infinity);

TEST :=
proc()
    local cases, inst, p, q, k;

    cases :=
    [[3, 64, 1/41], [5, 64, 1/41], [1, 32, 1/41],
     [1, 10, 1/11], [5, 3, 1], [7, 3, 2],
     [5, 48, 1/19], [7, 48, 1/13],
     [11, 16, 1/3], [13, 16, 1/8],
     [3, 16, 1/10], [1, 16, 1/32],
     [19, 4, 11/3], [21, 7, 32/19]];

    for inst in cases do
        p := inst[1]; q := inst[2]; k := inst[3];

        print(evalf(Q(p, q, k)),
              evalf(QQ(p, q, k)));
    od;
end;
```

This produces the following results for the test cases:

```
> TEST();
                                            -8
          [5., 48.97919294 + 0.2273921483 10   I], 48.97919294

                                            -9
          [3., 22.79234062 + 0.6739119228 10   I], 22.79234062

                                            -7
          [8., 148.7070193 + 0.1069863986 10   I], 148.7070193

                                            -8
          [2., 110.3747402 - 0.8833572709 10   I], 110.3747400

                                            -9
          [0., 1.603438998 + 0.5642199691 10   I], 1.603438998

                                            -9
          [0., 3.025326263 + 0.7216433442 10   I], 3.025326264

                                            -8
          [2., 21.50435498 + 0.1066992697 10   I], 21.50435498

                                            -8
          [1., 15.93501901 - 0.5378737091 10   I], 15.93501900

                                            -8
          [0., 3.156953436 + 0.1156017429 10   I], 3.156953434

                                            -9
          [0., 1.991146897 + 0.1577177352 10   I], 1.991146897

                                            -9
          [1., 12.52009747 + 0.6173768878 10   I], 12.52009747

                  [4., 35.54306350 + 0. I], 35.54306350

                                            -9
         [0., 0.9431219183 + 0.5926932608 10   I], 0.9431219179

                                            -9
         [0., 0.8236262644 - 0.4232839786 10   I], 0.8236262640

> quit
memory used=23.4MB, alloc=44.3MB, time=0.48
```

Comment: Always nice to see another way to employ contour integration.

Comment: Very kind indeed. I would have participated in real time if I hadn't made an arithmetic error that I did not detect until today which effectively blocked me from posting my contribution. Interesting thread.