# Integration using hypergeometric function

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function

I would like to calculate the definite integral
$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x(x^a + x^{-b})}$.
From Wolfram Alpha, the indefinite integral is
$x^b\ _2F_1(1;b/(a+b);b/(a+b)+1;x^{a+b})/b$ Where $_2F_1$ is the hypergeometric function. But I don’t know how to evaluate this at $x=0,\infty$. I tried to use equalities for hypergeometric function on wolfram, but they didn’t help.

I am also interested in the asymptotic behavior. What does $\log(x^b\ _2F_1(1;b/(a+b);b/(a+b)+1;x^{a+b})/b)$ look like?

Comment: $_2\text F_1(1,c;c+1;z)$ is a [Lerch phi](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/05/0025/) function

Comment: Using [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37372/323432) (or any of the answers in [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7Ba-1%7D%7D%7B1%2Bx%5Eb%7Ddx%24&p=1)), one gets that
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x(x^a+x^{-b})}dx=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{b-1}}{x^{a+b}+1}dx=\frac{\pi}{(a+b)\sin(\pi b/(a+b))},$$
for $a,b>0$.

Comment: Note that hypergeometric function is not good for evaluating this integral, since this ${}_2F_1$ series has radius of convergence $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting $y=\frac{1}{x^{a+b}+1}$ transforms the integral into a Beta function $$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{1}{a+b} \int_0^1  y^{\frac{a}{a+b}-1}(1-y)^{-\frac{a}{a+b}} d y \\
& =\frac{1}{a+b} B\left(\frac{b}{a+b}, \frac{a}{a+b}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Using the reflection property of Beta function:
$B(x, 1-x)=\pi \csc (\pi x) \textrm{ for } x\notin \mathbb{Z}$, we have

$$
I=\frac{1}{a+b} \pi \csc \left(\frac{b \pi}{a+b}\right)
$$

Wish it helps!

Comment: Nice and simple solution ! (+1)